# Library to compress a file as a.qzip

Tags: qt

I have some files whose extension is qzip, for example a.qzip.

It seems that those files are compressed with a library of qt.

Could anyone tell me what it is?

Thankyou very much.

Comment: Sure it's not gzip? qzip sounds unfamiliar. Take a look at its header  and see if you can find anything.

Comment: Well, doesn't ring a bell. Have you tried just unzipping it anyway? It could just be an incorrect file extension of a regular zip file.

Comment: @netrom  I have tried all I could do, and I am quite sure it is a correct file extension, I just know someone used one of a qt's library to compress it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this FAQ page](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_to_compress_data_with_qt):

> Qt uses the zlib library to provide compression. This means that you can compress and decompress your bytearrays of data using Qt. [...]
>
> Note that this **does not produce file archives that can be opened by other applications**, to do that you will need to write it yourself using Qt’s custom file handling system or use a 3rd party library.

Which if someone (lazily) created a file using [`qCompress()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qCompress) you would need to write your own code to read the file as a QByteArray then use the corresponding [`qUncompress()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qUncompress) method to read it. There is no official qzip format related to Qt that I know, so you should probably go and slap the developer who made these files if it works out!

In general, if you want to compress data that will be reusable, use a common file format.

Comment: +1 for slapping the developers if they expected this data to be useable outside their app. But maybe this data is purely meant for internal caching or history etc to the app, and the op is trying to inapproprietly access it.

Comment: @jdi  I can't ask the developer for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This was the only reference I have found on the entire www over qzip.

[quicklz](http://www.quicklz.com/)